# Cannot update UIButton.image after view loads

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am attempting something relatively simple. I have a UIButton that loads with an image:

```
@IBOutlet var peer5Outlet: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    peer5Outlet.enabled = true
    var img = UIImage(named: "camera")
    peer5Outlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "camera"),forState: UIControlState.Normal) }
```

Once it is loaded, I simply want to update that image by calling a method:

```
func updateButtonImage() {

    peer5Outlet.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "connected")!

    print("peer5Outlet.imageView!.image = \(peer5Outlet!.imageView!.image!)")

}
```

However, I am still unable to update the image; the original image never changes in the view.

Perhaps I am missing some sort of view reload method?

Comment: You need to set the image the same way as in `viewDidLoad`, via `setImage()`

Answer (score 3):

Update your `updateButtonImage` function to

```
func updateButtonImage() {
    peer5Outlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "connected"), forState: .Normal)
    print("peer5Outlet.imageView!.image = \(peer5Outlet!.imageView!.image!)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that worked.  

But let me trouble you for one more question - and forgive me if this is more appropriate for a separate post:  
  
My hope is to change the UIButton image from different class (Swift file). I do this by calling the method this way (SendSoundsViewControlller() is the VC with the method):  
  
                SendSoundsViewController().updateButtonImage()
  
But when I do this, the compiler tells me my UIButton is nil:  
  
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: That´s why it´s a different instance of the viewController. I can really recommend a new question or make a search there is a lot of posts at SO for this issue.

Comment: @CharlieStephenson here is a way you could do that http://stackoverflow.com/a/25204814/5576310

Comment: Ah, thank you. I will give this a try. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Np, did the above solution work for you @CharlieStephenson?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
peer5Outlet.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "connected"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Edit: In order to use the setImage method, you need to change the button's type to "Custom"...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the main thread whenever you're touching UIImage on UI

[GCD - main vs background thread for updating a UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370325/gcd-main-vs-background-thread-for-updating-a-uiimageview)

```
func updateButtonImage() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // update image
    }
}
```